# Bar Graph Latex

Tags: bar-chart

I don't understand why this code is only giving me the first 2 bars, and not all 3. The rest of the formatting is perfect, it's just incomplete.

What do I need to change?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Utterance Type,
    ylabel=Frequency,
    symbolic x coords={Question, Statement, Uncertain},
    xtick = data
    enlargelimits=1,
    ybar interval=0.4,
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Question,4073) (Statement,8541) (Uncertain,2044)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\caption{Overall Responses by Utterance Type}\label{Overall}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the following is closer to what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Utterance Type,
    ylabel=Frequency,
    symbolic x coords={Question, Statement, Uncertain},
    xtick = data,
    ybar,
    bar width=20pt,
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Question,4073) (Statement,8541) (Uncertain,2044)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\caption{Overall Responses by Utterance Type}\label{Overall}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thankyou, that's great!